# Neovim append method does not works on matchpairs

Tags: neovim, lua

I want to append `<:>` to vim.opt.matchpairs, which AFAIK is a string type.

Neovim lua doc says:

```lua
                                                            vim.opt:append()
Option:append(value)

    Append a value to string-style options. See :set+=

    These are equivalent:
        vim.opt.formatoptions:append('j')
        vim.opt.formatoptions = vim.opt.formatoptions + 'j'
```

I have this line on init.lua:

```lua
vim.o.matchpairs:append("<:>")
```

But Neovim returns an error:

```
...attempt to call method 'append' (a nil value)...
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you still have something open? How can we help you further? If the solution address your need maybe could you accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that `vim.o.matchpairs` is a string.

I would do:

```lua
vim.o.matchpairs = vim.o.matchpairs .. ",<:>"
```

or to take into account that `vim.o.matchpairs" could be empty

```lua
if not vim.o.matchpairs then
  vim.o.matchpairs = vim.o.matchpairs .. ","
end
vim.o.matchpairs = vim.o.matchpairs .. "<:>"
```

I suppose the confusion comes from `o` vs. `opt`.

You could also do:

```lua
vim.opt.matchpairs:append("<:>")
```

Comment: Oh lord… `vim.o` and `vim.opt` are different but the same? That seems like it could cause no end of confusion. Interesting to learn that `..` is also Lua's string concatenation operator, but `+` is the same as `:append`.

Comment: The `o` seems to be string versions of the `opt` versions. It allows to write Lua code that iterate over the `opt` version without having to split the `o` version into parts.